# how to take exact matched phrases using regular expression when multiple braces are present

Tags: python, regex, text-processing

I have texts like

```
1) <img="" id="">data</img>
2) (hi "hello") data (some text)
```

I want to remove only the text with braces and angular brackets and extract in between data. I tried

```
re.compile(r"\(.*\)")
re.compile(r"<.*>")
```

but since closing braces are at the end of text, whole text is getting deleted when re.sub is used.
How to take the only data in between multiple braces (angular or flower brackets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try non-greedy regular expressions, i.e.

```
re.compile(r"\(.*?\)")
re.compile(r"<.*?>")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [68]: re.sub(r'<(.+?)>', '', '<img="" id="">data</img>')
Out[68]: 'data'
```

Regex explanation:

```
<(.+?)>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/dRCzoEj0k9pnANPt)

```
In [68]: re.sub(r'\((.+?)\)', '', '(hi "hello") data (some text)')
Out[68]: ' data '
```

Regex explanation:

```
\((.+?)\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/9YhgsadiKl-9cXc-)

Read the section 'Watch Out for The Greediness!' at http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html